# Beautiful Soup string method behaving weirdly

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get an image in this page -
http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10161&langId=-1&programId=562&termId=100020629&divisionDisplayName=Stanford&departmentDisplayName=MATH&courseDisplayName=51&sectionDisplayName=01&demoKey=d&purpose=browse

I do the normal urllib open stuff (you need to track cookies if anyone's going to follow along) 
and do this

```
data =  soup.findAll("div",{"class":"efMaterialImage left"))
```

which works fine.

Weirdly, when I do `test = data.string`, and print the result, console shows 'None'.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `findAll` returns a list of matches, not a single match. A Python list does not have the attribute "string", however.

Try `data[0]` instead.

Edit:

String only seems to work if the tag has one child and its a string.
`<div>something</div>` would work, but `<div><p>something</p></div>` wouldn't.
Use more selectors or use `.contents` instead.

Comment: that prints out the correct content- but doesn't give me a string representation